# PHP unlink file with special chars in filename

Tags: php, special-characters, unlink

I can not delete file with special chars using unlink().
My file name contains for example '," and nothing happen
when I using unlink().
I tried to use addslashes and iconv, but it doesn't help..
Can anybody help me?
Filename for example: aaaż'.pdf

@Solution

```
$newFilename = str_replace('\\','',$filename);
$newFilename = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1250",$newFilename);
unlink($newFilename);
```

Comment: Instead of trying to delete files with special characters, try to remove special characters when uploading.. It will save you lots of trouble..

Comment: But the file is already saved in directory (I don't uploading it) and I have to delete it at the end of code.

Comment: Perhaps list a couple example filenames that can't be deleted?

Comment: For example filename: te'st.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = 'my\,file\,name';
unlink($filename);
```

Try adding antislashes, it should work.

addslashes() function doesn't add antislashes to ",".

Use str_replace() to do that:

```
 $filename = str_replace(',', '\,', $filename);
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists ? And do you have the permission to delete it?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, I found the solution myself. Thanks everybody for trying help.

Comment: You're welcome, edit your question to add your solution for others :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce that. Check the following example:

```
$filename = ",;\\'\"{}$!^#\n\t.txt";
touch($filename);
unlink($filename);
```

It works as expected.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - problem is when i combine ' with polish chars, for example: aaaż'.pdf (create it yourself, no with touch).

Comment: I don't know why, but now when I combine iconv() with str_replace() it works. Thanks for trying help.

Comment: @Rafael `$filename = "aaaż'.pdf";` worked for me. (I create the file with the shell, in PHP only unlinked it. Works fine.) .. It sounds like the incoming data, where you have the filename from is not UTF-8 where the filesystem is using `UTF-8` for filenames. In that case you need to use `iconv()` that's true. If the input encoding is `ISO-8859-1` then you can also use `utf8_encode()`..

Comment: That's exactly what it was.